# Start a non daemonized HAProxy?

Tags: 14.04

If I run the following:

```
service haproxy start
```

I created a haproxy daemon which runs in the background. How do I create a non daemon haproxy instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Or:

```
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```